# Prototype access denied, the proper way to handle it? "x" is not an "own property" of its parent

Tags: express, sequelize.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Like many others I've been getting this error when using Sequelize with Express and Express-handlebars:

`Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "first_name" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details
Handlebars: Access has been denied to resolve the property "last_name" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning:
See https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access for details`

I have found some answers on how to get around this. ie: **allowProtoMethods**, or adding **npm install @handlebars/allow-prototype-access**

What I'm curious about is, is there a proper way to handle the data or exclude the proto methods from the sequelize response?

I may not be understanding the issue at hand properly, so if that's the case I apologize. I'm just looking for the **"right"** way to deal with this.

Edit: To clarify a little further, I'm seeking to do things in a way that will produce the most secure application.

**From handlebarsjs.com:**
*`Using these properties may open security holes.`*

### **UPDATE!**

I'm still trying to work this issue out, but I've noticed an interesting behavior.

**Nested objects seem to trigger this issue.**

**It seems to trigger when the data in a nested object is accessed/rendered on the html page** (exa: {{contact.first_name}}

*sometimes it will have nested `dataValues` objects within the object and sometimes it won't.*

I'd provide an example including dataValues, but it hasn't displayed like that for a while.

**Object being returned:**

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "email": "email2@email.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$fOGiJC6NgUTR4qIt7/R7vuwpaFb3PUl9ks2vHBEkLnOUmRN0tEFue",
        "kind": "user",
        "createdAt": "2020-08-16T04:37:58.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-16T04:37:58.000Z",
        "Contact": {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Jane",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "gender": "female",
            "city": "Long Beach",
            "state": "CA",
            "zip": 12345,
            "phone_number": 1234567891,
            "createdAt": "2020-08-16T04:37:58.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-16T04:37:58.000Z",
            "UserId": 3
        },
        "Props": []
    }
```

*I'm not necessarily seeing any other explicit types of data that trigger this error message. (That's not to say that there aren't any, but so far every data type and script that I've passed hasn't caused a problem.)*

**Data I was having a problem with:** *This data is from a Sequelize query response shown above.*

```
let hbsObject = {
   user: data[0],
   contact: data[0].Contact
};
```

**Notes about what happened with this data:**

1. I used a promise to chain several queries at once.

   - User was queried, and contact was included in that query, so there were nested objects/data in the response. *(obviously)*
2. When I tried to render the first and last names from the data I was receiving the error message.

**Data that seems to have solved my error:**

```
let user = {
   id: data[0].id,
   email: data[0].email,
   kind: data[0].kind,
   createdAt: data[0].createdAt,
   updatedAt: data[0].updatedAt,
};

let hbsObject = {
  user: user,
  contact: data[0].Contact.dataValues,
};
```

*It's strange because sometimes when you view the data in the console, `dataValues` will be visible, and sometimes it won't. However, when you access it as I showed above the error is removed.*

#### Current Conclusion

- The data you are seeking to access on the handlebars page via the handlebars object must not be in a nested object.

**What does that mean?**

It seems to mean that you must either deconstruct it prior to passing the data to the page either manually *(like I did with `user`)* or by sending the data from the object 1 level at a time *(like I did with `contact`)*.

#### *If anyone can build on this or expand additional information I would greatly appreciate it! I'll edit again if more information becomes available.*

### **UPDATE2**

An array of objects is inaccessible as it is a list of objects nested in an array. This makes {{#each x}} a challenge. Individual data has been accessible with the method above.

### **UPDATE3**

I was unable to find any clear solution to this issue. In the end I just allowed the proto methods with the `handlebars/allow-prototype-access` package.

As long as you're the only one that has access to your template/you absolutely 100% trust whoever also has access to your template, then it shouldn't really be a problem. If that isn't the case, I'd suggest using something other than handlebars for now.